# Expected ';' at end of declarations list error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I declared the code

```
NSMutableArray *allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

however I get an error that is pointing at the = mark saying 
Expected ';' at end of declarations list error  and I do not think this is occurring with the spacing problem.  What is happening?

```
- (void) processImage:(UIImage *)image { //process captured image, crop, resize and rotate
    haveImage = YES;

    if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) { //Device is ipad
        // Resize image
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(768, 1022));
        [image drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1022)];
        UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 130, 768, 768);
        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([smallImage CGImage], cropRect);
        //or use the UIImage wherever you like

        [captureImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]];

        CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    }else{ //Device is iphone
        // Resize image
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, 426));
        [image drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 426)];
        UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 55, 320, 320);
        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([smallImage CGImage], cropRect);

        [captureImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]];

        CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    }

    //adjust image orientation based on device orientation
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        NSLog(@"landscape left image");

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        captureImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(-90));
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        NSLog(@"landscape right");

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        captureImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(90));
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        NSLog(@"upside down");
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        captureImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(180));
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
        NSLog(@"upside upright");
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        captureImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(0));
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        NSArray *directoryNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hats",@"bottoms",@"right",@"left",nil];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder

        for (int i = 0; i < [directoryNames count] ; i++) {
            NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[directoryNames objectAtIndex:i]];
            if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil]; //Create folder

        NSString *folderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"hats"]; // "right" is at index 2, per comments & code
        NSString *filePath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"IMAGE_NAME_HERE.PNG"]; // you maybe want to incorporate a timestamp into the name to avoid duplicates
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(captureImage.image);
        [imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    }
    }



}
```

Comment: Maybe you have a syntax error before this line.

Comment: your error is most likely coming from somewhere else, post more code

Comment: I put some code in so everyone could see

Comment: `NSMutableArray *allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` where is this statement in code?

Comment: I am putting that in the declaration .h file

Comment: I don't believe you usually initialise variables in a .h file in Objective C. At least in my case, Xcode always complain if I tried to.

Comment: Its because I want to save a photo into a directory ¥. I need to declare the array

Comment: You can declare the NSMutableArray *allImagesArray in your .h file and then in your init() method of the .m file, you put allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: `NSMutableArray *allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]allImagesArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];`You are saying this rite? it still won't work I even got more errors.

Comment: No, I mean NSMutableArray *allImagesArray; in your .h and then in the init() of the .m file, you put allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; Remove the "= [[NSMutableArray alloc]]" in your .h file.

Comment: `NSMutableArray *allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; `Now I am geting and error saying expected ]

Answer (score 0):

For sake of clarity in the discussion, what I mean is your header file (the .h file) should look like this:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------
// This is your class header file (it has a .h extension)
// --------------------------------------------------------
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyClass : UIViewController
{
    // ----------------------------------------------
    // Declare your array here in the header file
    // ----------------------------------------------
    NSMutableArray *allImagesArray;
}

@end
```

And then in your implementation file (the .m file)

```
// --------------------------------------------------------
// This is your implementation file (it has a .m extension)
// --------------------------------------------------------

@implementation MyClass

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self)
    {
       // -----------------------------------------------
       // Initialise your array here
       // -----------------------------------------------

       allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

// the rest of your code 

@end
```

### Update

Yes, you can also initialise your array in the viewDidLoad(). That's probably where you should do it :D

What I am saying is don't write this:

```
NSMutableArray *allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

**That is not valid syntax.**

The syntax to declare and initialise is like this:

```
NSMutableArray *allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

But you cannot put that in the header file. So you should not do this:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------
// This is your class header file (it has a .h extension)
// --------------------------------------------------------
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyClass : UIViewController
{
    // ----------------------------------------------
    // Don't write it like this
    // ----------------------------------------------
    NSMutableArray *allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

@end
```

Comment: so that means I can just delete     `NSMutableArray *allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; ` that was in my view did load rite?